# Calculating with a specific Riemannian metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I understand the idea of Riemannian metric, it takes to tangent vectors in a point $x$ of a manifold $M$ and defines an scalar product between them. My problem is how to compute the scalar product of two vectors when I have an specific Riemannian metric $g$. For example, I know that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a possible metric is the usual metric, so $\langle u,v\rangle=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3$. I also know that in that case $g=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$. How are the calculations made in order to get
$$
g(u,v)=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3 \ ?
$$
How would we make it if $g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$? This seems to be the normalized metric, but I struggle in order to do calculations with it.

Comment: Do you know how $g = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ gives $g(u, v) = u_1v_1+ u_2v_2 + u_3v_3$?

Comment: No, that's my main problem, how to go from a specific expression of $g$ to  the formula of the scalar product it generates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty computational answer, which I think is sufficient based on your question. Let $u= u_1e_1+u_2e_2+u_3e_3$ and $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2+v_3e_3$ where the $e_i$ are the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Then each of the terms $dx^2,dy^2,dz^2$ acts bilinearly on $2$-tuples of vectors. For example,

\begin{align}
dx^2(u,v)&=dx^2(u_1e_1+u_2e_2+u_3e_3,v_1e_1+v_2e_2+v_3e_3)\\
&=\sum^3_{i=1} \sum^3_{j=1} u_i v_j dx^2(e_i,e_j)
\end{align}

Now, long story short, the $dx^2,$ $dy^2,$ $dz^2$ are defined in such a way (they're the $\textit{dual basis}$ to the $e_i$) that we have $dx^2(e_1,e_1)=1$, $dy^2(e_2,e_2)=1$, $dz^2(e_2,e_2)=1$, and they're equal to $0$ otherwise. So the above sum reduces to
$$dx^2(u,v)=\sum^3_{i=1} \sum^3_{j=1} u_i v_j dx^2(e_i,e_j)=u_1 v_1 dx^2(e_1,e_1)=u_1 v_1.$$

Similarly, we have $dy^2(u,v)=u_2 v_2$ and $dz^2(u,v)=u_3 v_3$. So, this is just the standard inner product since $g(u,v)=dx^2(u,v)+dy^2(u,v)+dz^2(u,v)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I understand know how those $dx_i^2$ work. In the case of $\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, how would I apply that part in the denominator to a couple of vectors?

Comment: It just goes along for the ride. Think of it as $f(x,y,z)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$, so when you apply it to $2$-tuples, only the $dx^2$, etc. act on the tuples. See what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Okay, then $\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(u,v)=\frac{u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

Comment: Technically, yes. But you will rarely see metrics written this way (I guess besides the Euclidean one). Usually we let the metric act on all the combinations of the basis vectors (i.e. compute $g_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$) and then form the matrix $(g_{ij})$ that represents the metric in coordinates (you will come across this if you haven't already).

Comment: Okay, I see. I've asked the question precesely because I have to prove the isometry between to Riemman manifolds, and the second one is $\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$ where the given metric is $g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. In this case I guess $$(g_{ij})=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}I$$